# how to implement Card Sorting code using helper function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Thank you for the help, i am still early in learning to program so bear with me. I am asked to fix the sorting function to place the cards in the correct order of suit.

If you sort the cards without using a custom sort function:

```
print(sorted(deck.cards))
```

you receive:

```
['10♠', '10♡', '10♢', '10♣', '2♠', '2♡', '2♢', '2♣', '3♠', '3♡', '3♢', '3♣', '4♠', '4♡', '4♢', '4♣', '5♠', '5♡', '5♢', '5♣', '6♠', '6♡', '6♢', '6♣', '7♠', '7♡', '7♢', '7♣', '8♠', '8♡', '8♢', '8♣', '9♠', '9♡', '9♢', '9♣', 'A♠', 'A♡', 'A♢', 'A♣', 'J♠', 'J♡', 'J♢', 'J♣', 'K♠', 'K♡', 'K♢', 'K♣', 'Q♠', 'Q♡', 'Q♢', 'Q♣']
```

I must fix this using a custom sorting function.
The correct response should be:

```
['10♢', '10♣', '10♡', '10♠', '2♢', '2♣', '2♡', '2♠', '3♢', '3♣', '3♡', '3♠', '4♢', '4♣', '4♡', '4♠', '5♢', '5♣', '5♡', '5♠', '6♢', '6♣', '6♡', '6♠', '7♢', '7♣', '7♡', '7♠', '8♢', '8♣', '8♡', '8♠', '9♢', '9♣', '9♡', '9♠', 'A♢', 'A♣', 'A♡', 'A♠', 'J♢', 'J♣', 'J♡', 'J♠', 'K♢', 'K♣', 'K♡', 'K♠', 'Q♢', 'Q♣', 'Q♡', 'Q♠']
```

I must:

- use the sorted function
- write a custom sort helper function that you can pass to sorted via the key parameter
- return a new list of cards
- the suits should be in ♢,♣,♡,♠ order

I am confused in the direction i should be taking.

So far i have brainstormed my helper function to iterate through the second part of each item because this corresponds to the suit.

```
def sort_helper(x):
  return x[1]

def card_sorter_v1(p):
  x = sorted(p, key=sort_helper)
  return x
print(card_sorter_v1(cards))
```

This only sorts the suits correctly for the first number though. I am not sure how to target an iteration through each number. Is the problem in my helper function? or main function?

Comment: `key` must be a function that returns an object that can be compared by the usual means. What information do you need to return from this function?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python sorting tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```py
>>> xs = ['10♠', '10♡', '10♢', '10♣', '2♠', '2♡', '2♢', '2♣', '3♠', '3♡', '3♢', '3♣', '4♠', '4♡', '4♢', '4♣', '5♠', '5♡', '5♢', '5♣', '6♠', '6♡', '6♢', '6♣', '7♠', '7♡', '7♢', '7♣', '8♠', '8♡', '8♢', '8♣', '9♠', '9♡', '9♢', '9♣', 'A♠', 'A♡', 'A♢', 'A♣', 'J♠', 'J♡', 'J♢', 'J♣', 'K♠', 'K♡', 'K♢', 'K♣', 'Q♠', 'Q♡', 'Q♢', 'Q♣']
>>> custom_order = {'♢':1, '♣': 2, '♡': 3, '♠': 4}
>>> sorted(xs, key=lambda x: (x[0], custom_order[x[-1]]))
['10♢', '10♣', '10♡', '10♠', '2♢', '2♣', '2♡', '2♠', '3♢', '3♣', '3♡', '3♠', '4♢', '4♣', '4♡', '4♠', '5♢', '5♣', '5♡', '5♠', '6♢', '6♣', '6♡', '6♠', '7♢', '7♣', '7♡', '7♠', '8♢', '8♣', '8♡', '8♠', '9♢', '9♣', '9♡', '9♠', 'A♢', 'A♣', 'A♡', 'A♠', 'J♢', 'J♣', 'J♡', 'J♠', 'K♢', 'K♣', 'K♡', 'K♠', 'Q♢', 'Q♣', 'Q♡', 'Q♠']
>>>
```

Explanation:

- You assign ascending numbers to the symbol you want to sort.
- Use these ascending numbers for sorting.
- Pay attention to the `-1` here: `x[-1]`. Your function uses `x[1]`, and the problem is that it will take the `0` in `10♠` instead of the last character.

You can take a similar approach if you need to sort the cards like this: A, 2, 3, ..., 9, 10, J, Q, K